# How to extract percentage every 10 seconds from this lines?

Tags: python, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show the rsync --progress in web browser using DJango?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523931/how-to-show-the-rsync-progress-in-web-browser-using-django)

I have this linux command:

```
rsync -avz --info=progress2 source:/file /destination
```

which I have used in Python like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '-avz', '--info=progress2', source12, destination], 
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

This store the output as well as progress in proc variable like this:

```
receiving incremental file list
rathi/
rathi/20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt.gz
    209,398,969  27%   11.95MB/s    0:00:45
```

I only want to extract the progress percentage from the above line. I want to check the variable for each 1minute and extracts the updated percentage. For the parsing I think can use `re` module. How can I achieve my result? Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523931/how-to-show-the-rsync-progress-in-web-browser-using-django

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work!

Comment: Did not work is a pointless feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the progress with re indeed.

```
progress = re.search('\d*%',str).group()
```

Where str is your string to search in.

Edit:

You need to make a while loop e.g.

```
while(progress < 101%):
    get_new_progress
    re.search....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I got the percentage. How do I check the variable for each minute and get the updated percentage every time? Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer, consider that pseudo code. You can use int() to convert the progress to an integer to use in the while loop.

Comment: Yes, That could work! I will try and let you know. Thanks